# Get associative array from raw sql query in django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am developing an django web application. I am using raw sql queries without using models. Below is the code what I have till now.

```
def getCntlData(self, FID, PID):
        sqlst = 'select * from employee where employeeid = %s'    
        cursor.execute(sqlst, [PID])
        data_row = cursor.fetchall()

        return data_row
```

The data I want is in the format of Associative array or in the form of dictionary, like what PHP gives on querying mysql.
[{"employeename":"Max","employeeage":"34"}]

Answer (score 0):

From Django documentation of [preforming raw SQL queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/)

> By default, the Python DB API will return results without their field
>   names, which means you end up with a list of values, rather than a
>   dict. At a small performance and memory cost, you can return results
>   as a dict by using something like this:
>
> ```
> def dictfetchall(cursor):
>     "Return all rows from a cursor as a dict"
>     columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
>     return [
>         dict(zip(columns, row))
>         for row in cursor.fetchall()
>     ]
> ```